# Removing duplicate records from CSV file using Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, grouping, distinct-values

I would like to remove duplicate records from a [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) file using Python Pandas.
The CSV file contains records with three attributes, *scale*, *minzoom*, and *maxzoom*. I want to have a resulting dataframe with *minzoom* and *maxzoom* and the records left being unique.

I.e.,

Input CSV file (lookup_scales.csv)

```
Scale, minzoom, maxzoom
2000, 0, 15
3000, 0, 15
10000, 8, 15
20000, 8, 15
200000, 15, 18
250000, 15, 18
```

Required distinct_lookup_scales.csv (Without scale column)

```
minzoom, maxzoom
0,5
8,15
15,18
```

My code so far is

```
lookup_scales_df = pd.read_csv('C:/Marine/lookup/lookup_scales.csv', names = ['minzoom','maxzoom'])
lookup_scales_df = lookup_scales_df.set_index([2, 3])
file_name = "C:/Marine/lookup/distinct_lookup_scales.csv"
lookup_scales_df.groupby('minzoom', 'maxzoom').to_csv(file_name, sep=',')
```

Comment: why not just `np.unique(df['minzoom', 'maxzoom'])`

Comment: Hi mad, thanks. Is np numpy?. Forgive me I am new to python. Dave

Comment: It is not very clear what you are trying to achieve with groupby. If you just want to remove the duplicate use numpy.

Comment: yeah it is. most people in python `import numpy as np`  so when a numpy module is called it is np.module

Comment: Thanks d_kennetz. Will I be able to save the filtered dataframe to a new csv like I was trying to do above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need NumPy or anything. You can just do the unique-ify in one line, while importing the CSV file using Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('lookup_scales.csv', usecols=['minzoom', 'maxzoom']).drop_duplicates(keep='first').reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   minzoom  maxzoom
0        0       15
1        8       15
2       15       18
```

Then to write it out to a CSV file:

```
df.to_csv(file_name, index=False) # You don't need to set sep in this because to_csv makes it comma-delimited.
```

So the whole code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('lookup_scales.csv', usecols=['minzoom', 'maxzoom']).drop_duplicates(keep='first').reset_index()
file_name = "C:/Marine/lookup/distinct_lookup_scales.csv"
df.to_csv(file_name, index=False) # You don't need to set sep in this, because to_csv makes it comma-delimited.
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `pd.read_csv()`, `pd.to_csv()` and `drop_duplicates()`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep=', ', engine='python')

new_df = df[['minzoom','maxzoom']].drop_duplicates()

new_df.to_csv('out.csv', index=False)
```

Outputs to `out.csv`:

```
minzoom,maxzoom
0,15
8,15
15,18
```

Note `sep=', '` when reading `test.csv`, otherwise your column names with contain a leading space if left with default `sep=','`.

Comment: Thanks rahlf23 This is also exactly what I was hoping for result wise. Sincerely appreciated. Really appreciated the diff approach. Dave

Answer (score 0):

[The answer provided by d_kennetz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52634045/5211833) is completely wrong. The correct way of doing this while keeping other columns intact is by replacing `h`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('yourcsvfilehere.csv').drop_duplicates('columnnamehere',keep='first')
```

Comment: It probably doesn't matter that much. Pandas is a homework tag, and there are probably *literally* tens of thousands of duplicates to this question. One duplicate less or one duplicate more doesn't matter (incl. the answers).

Comment: cont' - The homework assignments are generated by scripts to be unique to each student (with unique data), but there are very few really different questions. Thus the homework sweatshop (possibly with [payment behind the scenes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417632/request-to-let-banned-users-ask-one-question-every-week#comment906279_417632)).